# 'ING' FORM in sentence

Tags: grammar, ielts

which sentence is correct and Why:

**Sentence 1** : This aims to help people part buy a house or a flat by making housing more affordable for first-time buyers,and possibly **taking** the strain away form elderly parents.

**Sentence 2** : This aims to help people part buy a house or a flat by making housing more affordable for first-time buyers,and possibly **takes** the strain away form elderly parents.

Comment: It's just a matter of whether you're linking ***taking*** to preceding *by **making*** OR ***takes*** to preceding *This **aims***. Both are perfectly credible, and it's not obvious to me there's any point in trying to identify some difference in "nuance of meaning". Personally I have no particular preference one way or the other - use whichever you like best.

Comment: I think the word "part" should not be in either sentence.